# Xamarin Android AdMob returns Failed to load ad: 3

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, admob

I've built an android application with Xamarin that is published on playstore.
Here admob banner are shown correctly but, since a few weeks ago, banner are not shown in my developer version of the app.

The error returned is: Failed to load ad: 3

The only thing I did was to update Visual Studio to the latest version and update some google packages into the project.

Can these updates be the reason of my problems?
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself.
After 1 week of attempts I tried to compile app signing it for distribution and banners appeared.
In past, for Admob, app sign wasn't mandatory for showing banners but actually seems to be.

Hope this can help someone in future.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, @Badozvora. This has helped me. I also faced the same issue.

Comment: Great @Mac, I'm glad I helped you